# Is cinnamon an effective method to relieve the symptoms of the flu?

Tags: natural-remedies, flu

[This article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/390832-how-was-cinnamon-used-as-a-folk-medicine-for-the-flu/) mentions that cinnamon is used to treat flu symptoms.

Is there scientific evidence it would be an effective method to treat the flu symptoms?

Comment: Cleaned obsolete comments.